# How to compare two text views in Android Studio Espresso

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm new to Espresso in Android Studio.  The app I'm testing sends information to a REST service which creates and sends back an ID number.  In another piece of the app I can request that ID number and get its information back.  I want to store the ID returned when created and insert it into the requester to verify it is created.  I've found some Espresso methods which can get a string from a view, but it warns that that is dangerous and likely not the best way to do that.  [how to get text from textview using espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23381459/how-to-get-text-from-textview-using-espresso)

Can someone explain the best way to accomplish this task if getting a string is not a good idea?  Or, is that the only way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is if a instrumentation test is really what you want to do in your case. If something is testable in a easy way depends on your architecture. Large integration tests tend to break often as they hold many dependencies - consider to write unit tests first and https://testing.googleblog.com/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html is also a good read regarding that topic.